# How to track screen views and display it in app in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Let's say I'm making a blog app. I want to display the number of people who saw this specific post. Basically, if I have ten posts, I want to display the number of people saw each by opening it on the new Flutter page. I want to do this so people can basically see what is trending and click on that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set a counter at backend server api that how many times a blog post is called for fetching details. This can be a field for filter, sorting, display in app then.